# Can Excel have a persistent data connection when loaded as an unopened attachment in Smartsheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros

I have an Odata source that I have mapped as a data source in Excel. I can schedule that to run in the background and continuously update the data file. I need to now attach this excel file to a Smartsheet file in order for the Smartsheet data importer to bring the excel data into Smartsheet.

Issues - Because Smartsheet cannot directly bring in Data from Odata, I am trying to leverage the native excel connection to Odata and the Smartsheet data importer to automate any data updates.

Is there any way, using VBA to create a Macro to create a persistent connection in the excel sheet to the Odata source even when stored as an attachment in Smartsheet?

I appreciate any VBA and Macro experts - I have hit my limit in my technical abilities and Google searches have not proved useful. I am trying to solution something for a customer that removes the need for an API and allows them to leverage the Odata source.

Comment: I never came across with OData but confident enough to say that once you try the POWER QUERY and if through then you may record the process as a MACRO.

Comment: Another I found few links from my archive of VBA programing, you may go with it also,, Link 1,, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/marcelolr/2010/02/18/consuming-odata-with-office-vba-part-iii-excel/  Link 2,, http://cdn.cdata.com/help/RDA/xls/pg_excelmacroex.htm ,, I do believe that these may fix the issue ☺